# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::remember()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I was trying to cache the db query with built in function remember(). But it doesn't seem to be working fine. Here is fine snippets.

```
$categories = Category::orderBy('rank', 'asc')
            ->select('id', 'name', 'rank')
            ->where('parentid', '=', 0)
            ->where('id', '<>', 4)
            ->remember(300)
            ->get();
```

This is the reference [link](https://bosnadev.com/2014/12/27/laravel-caching-database-queries/), which I was following. I am getting the following error messa

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::remember()

**Category.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
 //
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This functionality was **removed** in Laravel 5. However, you can still bring it back by following the tutorial behind [this link](https://www.neontsunami.com/posts/bringing-the-remember-method-back-to-laravel-5). It's using the [dwightwatson/rememberable](https://github.com/dwightwatson/rememberable) package.

A **better and future proof way** of resolving this issue, is using the **[Cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache) method**. This functionality is available from Laravel 4.2 onwards.